# Authenticate Android App

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am new to android and I am building an app that I want to authenticate using the local users google account.  Unfortunately I have gotten myself in a bit of a bind looking at Auth 2.0 and logging in via the google services.

What is the recommended route to authenticate (and hopefully not require typing a login name)?  I tried many of the samples that I saw but much of it seems deprecated.

Any example code would be very helpful as well.

I was using this tutorial but it is a bit outdated and I believe that it is much simplier now.

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it.  Don't know if it is the recommended approach but it works...

in OnCreate of my entry activity (main) I put...

```
 AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
 Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
 AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> futur;
 futur = accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0],AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE_USERINFO_PROFILE, null, null,
                new OnTokenAcquired(), new Handler(new OnError()));
```

In that same activity I created...

```
private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
            // Get the result of the operation from the AccountManagerFuture.
            Bundle bundle;
            try {
                bundle = result.getResult();
                // The token is a named value in the bundle. The name of the
                // value
                // is stored in the constant AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN.
                String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                //If token isn't null then let them in and also make sure Crunchy accounts are created
                if(token!=null){
                    ProcessToken pt = new ProcessToken(token);
                    pt.execute("");
                    }

                Intent launch = (Intent) bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                if (launch != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(launch, 0);
                    return;
                }
            }catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also created an asyncTask to process the token (because I do a bit more logic to setup account and set a cookie).  It looks like this (much of my processing/cookie logic is not completed yet)

```
      package com.craig.activities.login;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class ProcessToken extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Long>{

    private static final String AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=";
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "OnTokenAcquired.class";
    private static String token="";

    public ProcessToken(String tokenValue){
        token=tokenValue;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL+token);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int serverCode= con.getResponseCode();
            if(serverCode==200){
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "code 200!!!");
                                //PUT MY LOGIC IN HERE....
                }
            else{
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Oops, We had an error on authentication");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
     }
```

Not sure if this is the best but it seems to be working for me....